# how to ignore the assignment intendation in any python formatter (black, yapf, autopep8)

Tags: python-3.x, formatting, autopep8, yapf

i would like my code to look like following:

```
short          = value
long_name      = value
very_long_name = value
```

instead all python formatter give the following result:

```
short = value
long_name = value
very_long_name = value
```

the latter is harder to read in my opinion, so i would like to skip assignment indentations. To my knowledge, there are no settings for such a configuration. Neither for autopep, yapf and black.

with black I had tried --skip-string-normalisation, but it didn't do anything

with autopep8 I had tried severall options, --ignore E20, E221, E251 ... but none worked
https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/#features